# jquery subscribe to function return error

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

Have following function that is called by multiple elements's change event.

```
function multipleTests(){
    if(Test_X == false){
        return false;
    }
    if(Test_Y == false){
        return false;
    }
    // all tests passed release save button
    releaseButton();
}
```

I want to subscript to the "return false event". something like this:

```
multipleTest.bind("return false", function(){
    // do something here, like reset fields, other tests etc.
});
```

Must I change the *function* multipleTests?

Can I use *try catch* somehow?

Can I use a promise object somehow?

Comment: Just for clarity, are you saying that you'd like to _always_ run the new function whenever the function `multipleTests` is called?

Comment: I.e. I want to run a second function when the "multipleTests()" executes "return false" only

Comment: Create function `returnFalse()`. Call function when test is false. Bind `returnFalse`.

Comment: I see - so I suppose, in theory what you're asking is whether it's possible to run function `b` whenever function `b` is called, without altering function `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is create and trigger a custom event:

```js
// create your custom event
var customEvent = new CustomEvent('my-custom-event',{
  detail: {
    tests: {
      x: null,
      y: null
    }
  }
});


// Listen for the event.
// You have to do this BEFORE dispatching the event
document.addEventListener('my-custom-event', function (e) {
   // print out the event detail
  console.log(JSON.stringify(e.detail));
}, false);

//triggered when the button is clicked
function multipleTests(){
  var Test_X = true;
  var Test_Y = false;
  
  //assign the outcome of the tests to the event detail
  customEvent.detail.tests.x = Test_X;
  customEvent.detail.tests.y = Test_Y;
  
  if(Test_X == false){
    document.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
    return false;
  }
  if(Test_Y == false){
    document.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
    return false;
  }
  // all tests passed release save button
//   releaseButton();
}
```

```html
<input type=button value="trigger event" onclick="multipleTests()"/>
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events